# Postgresql - use JOIN with UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I want to `UPDATE` table row in `member_network` table using `WHERE` clause by `team_id = 91` and using `JOIN`.

Main table `member_network` structure look like:

```
| id |  network_profile_name |                              
|----------------------------|
|  1 |    John Doe           |
```

I have two fields in two more connected tables with the values I need.

Table `team_member_network` structure looks like:

```
| id | team_member_id | member_network_id |
|----|----------------|-------------------|
|  2 |             1  |                 1 |
```

Table `team_member`:

```
| id    | team_id | member_id |
| ------|---------|-----------|
| 1     |      91 |   1679817 |
```

This is some kind of reverse relationship

My work so far:

```
   UPDATE member_network
        SET
            network_profile_name = 'James Bond'
        JOIN team_member_network
            ON member_network.id = team_member_network.member_network_id
        JOIN team_member
            ON team_member_network.team_member_id = team_member.id
        WHERE team_id = 91;
```

With an error:

> Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "JOIN\

Works on `SELECT` but how should I use `JOIN` when updating selected row? Related posts I found did not help in my case..

Comment: `UPDATE member_network
        SET
            network_profile_name = 'James Bond' from member_network`

Comment: Duplicate alias: 7 ERROR:  table name \"member_network\" specified more than once @Jens

Comment: try to use aliases

Comment: I am using team_id to update column in member_network table @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: But the value is not used in the UPDATE part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would need JOIN for this:

```
UPDATE member_network mn
  SET network_profile_name = 'James Bond'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM team_member_network tmn
                JOIN team_member tm ON tmn.team_member_id = tm.id
              WHERE mn.id = tmn.member_network_id
                AND tm.team_id = 91);
```

If you really want to "join" the tables, then you need to do that in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) you need a FROM clause first - but that should **not** repeat the target table.

```
UPDATE member_network mn
  SET network_profile_name = 'James Bond'
FROM team_member_network tmn
  JOIN team_member tm ON tmn.team_member_id = tm.id
WHERE mn.id = tmn.member_network_id --<< this is the "join" to the target table
  AND tm.team_id = 91;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. I am now more aware of how this should be handled. I used your example. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the  comma (,) in the end of the line

```
network_profile_name = 'James Bond',
```

then try it should work

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post as I already fix that. But the issue is the same. @VasanthR

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.field = t2.'value'
from table2 t2
where t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

In your case:

```
   UPDATE member_network
        SET
            network_profile_name = 'James Bond'
        FROM team_member
        JOIN team_member
            ON team_member_network.team_member_id = team_member.id
        WHERE team_id = 91 and
            member_network.id = team_member_network.member_network_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get an error:
Duplicate alias: 7 ERROR: table name \"member_network\" specified more than once @LajosArpad

Comment: You should **not** repeat the target table of the update in the `FROM` clause

Comment: Without FROM it's  Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near \"JOIN\ @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @FilipStojavonic thanks for pointing that out, I sent the answer too quickly initially. I have edited now. Can you test it?